# What do chickens eat?

Tags: pixel-piracy

I managed to capture a chicken, but about 45 minutes later it starved to death.  There were watermelons and fruit on the deck of the ship.  What do chickens eat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animal starvation was a [bug.](http://steamcommunity.com/games/264140/announcements/detail/1769099195446213132)  As of now, they eat nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try feeding chickens with grains and seeds. 
More exactly, hen pellets (or crumbles which are the same thing but smaller).

Comment: Are those sold in the food shop?  I haven't seen them yet.